# Neo4j: ordering output by values in a collection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working with data from a csv file which contains four columns of data: `stationID`, `stationName`, `stationLong`, `stationLat` where `stationID` is the unique number of the station, `stationName` is the name of the station, `stationLong` is the longitude of the location of the station and `stationLat` is the latitude of the location of the station.

Sample data as follows:

Row 1 `1, "Cranbourne", 22.6932, 100.5347`

Row 2 `2, "Dandenong", 25.6589, 98.5679`

Row 3 `3, "Flinders Street", 33.1674, 66.3287`

This data has been loaded into Neo4J and is labelled `Station`.

I have run a query to get the distances from from each station to all other stations. For example, the distances between station "Cranbourne" to "Dandenong", "Cranbourne" to "Flinders Street" and so on.

```
MATCH (s1: Station), (s2: Station)
WHERE s1 <> s2
RETURN s1.stationName AS `Station`, collect([s2.stationName, round(distance(
    point({longitude: s1.stationLong, latitude: s1.stationLat}),
    point({longitude: s2.stationLong, latitude: s2.stationLat})))]) AS `Distance to all other stations`
```

Output:

First row: `"Cranbourne", [["Dandenong", 15], ["Flinders Street", 45], ["Springvale", 25], ["Yarraman", 19]]`

This output is what I want in terms of results, however is there a way to ensure that the output is ordered by ascending distances from the station?

Desired output:

First row: `"Cranbourne", [["Dandenong", 15], ["Yarraman", 19], ["Springvale", 25], ["Flinders Street", 45]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the data before you `COLLECT` it:

```
MATCH (s1: Station), (s2: Station)
WHERE s1 <> s2
WITH
  s1.stationName AS Station, s2.stationName AS sn2,
  round(distance(
    point({longitude: s1.stationLong, latitude: s1.stationLat}),
    point({longitude: s2.stationLong, latitude: s2.stationLat}))) AS dist
ORDER BY dist
RETURN Station, COLLECT([sn2, dist]) AS `Distance to all other stations`
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- get the values that you sort on separately before you do the COLLECT.
- using apoc.coll.sort or apoc.coll.sortMaps   to sort after you have COLLECTed